# A question about positive definite matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

$\mathbf{A}$ is a real positive definite matrix. Show that there exists an upper triangular matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}$, and all the numbers on the diagonal of matrix $\mathbf{B}$ are negative.  Here $\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{T}}$ denotes the transpose of $\mathbf{B}$.
As we konw, a real positive definite matrix is congruent to an identity matrix. So,  there exists a matrix $\mathbf{C}$ such that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{T}}$. But how to prove that numbers on the diagonal of matrix $\mathbf{C}$ are negative?

Comment: Positive definite means symmetric, too, doesn't it? Since some peoply define being positive definite without symmetry of $A$...

Comment: Please answer to @Meowdog: is your matrix $A$ symmetric as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of $A$:

$$A=LL^T$$

where $L$ is known to be upper triangular with $>0$ diagonal entries and take

$$C=-L$$.